# How to update an href if variable in URL is defined

Tags: javascript

I have an AMP layout, where a code is appended to the URL based on the traffic source, this code then updates the phone numbers on the site.

For example, https://example.com/text?bid=1234

I have written the following script, which if a bid code is set in the existing URL, should update any links on the page to include the above bid ID but it doesn't appear to be working:

```js
  $(function() {
    updateLinksHref();
});

  function updateLinksHref() {
    var bid = getUrlParameter('bid');
    if(bid == undefined ){
      bid = localStorage.getItem('bid');
    }else{
      localStorage.setItem('bid',bid)
    }

    if (bid && bid !== undefined) {
        $.each($('a'), function(i, link) {
            if ($(link).attr('href') !== '' || $(link).attr('href') !== '#') {

                $(link).attr('href', $(link).attr('href') + '?bid=' + bid)
            }
        });
    }
}

var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

Looking at the local storage, bid is then set as 1234 (as expected) but the hrefs in the html aren't being updated

Comment: Does it give an error at any particular line? Have you used your browser debugger to make sure variables, like `bid` are being set to what you expect?

Comment: Can you please confirm there's no error in the console log?

Comment: can you provide your HTML code? and try creating a demo.

Comment: this works like you posted for me.
See: 
https://jsfiddle.net/0f3uhkpe/2/
http://fiddle.jshell.net/0f3uhkpe/2/show/light/?bid=123

Note, that I did change the first line in getUrlParameter to use the searchQuery param from the top frame, as jsfiddle will create the output in an iframe.
However your code works ...

Maybe you do have the same setup (with frames) on your page.
Try stepping through your code in debugger and see if window.location.search is containing what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

For my own reference, the following code worked:

```js
  $(function() {
    updateLinksHref();
});

  function updateLinksHref() {
    var bid = getUrlParameter('bid');
    if(bid == undefined ){
      bid = localStorage.getItem('bid');
    }else{
      localStorage.setItem('bid',bid)
    }

    if (bid && bid !== undefined) {
        $.each($('a'), function(i, link) {
            if ($(link).attr('href') !== '' || $(link).attr('href') !== '#') {

                $(link).attr('href', $(link).attr('href') + '?bid=' + bid)
            }
        });
    }
}

var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

I had to ensure the following was loaded:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```